# How can you write a script that will read files and remember a line?

Tags: python-2.7, memory

So, I need to write a script that lets the program look into each folder, into the .txt file, read a number, and store it into its memory. Also, I need it to loop so the script can run and look at multiple directories so it can find the number in the files. That way, with the numbers, I can make a bar graph. I am confused on opening multiple files and storing the number into the memory.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a place where you can learn, obtain and share knowledge. It's not a place where users ask for code. Kindly, add your code and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few lines to get you started:

```
import glob
data = {}
filespec = r"E:\data\*\*.txt"
for filename in glob.iglob(filespec):
    with open(filename) as textfile:
        for line in textfile:
            if line.startswith("This is the number you want:"):
                data[filename] = line.split(":")[1]
                break
for filename, number in data.items():
    print filename,number
```

Now, I don't really think your textfiles have lines in them that say

```
This is the number you want: 42
```

but you haven't given us much to go on about what they *do* look like. And I also don't think your files reside in a folder called `E:\data`. You will have to edit both lines yourself before the code will do anything.